# JSON Array Question

Tags: json, jsp

How to use jsp to get json resulting in folowing format ?

```
{

     "firstName": "John",

     "lastName": "Smith",

    "address": {

         "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",

         "city": "New York",

         "state": "NY",

         "postalCode": 10021

     },

     "phoneNumbers": [

        "212 732-1234",

        "646 123-4567"

    ]

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code with the "101010" toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: What form is the input data in?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Normally don't use a JSP at all to "get" JSON. A smart guy would just have printed the above string as-is. So there must be more into the story. What exactly is the functional requirement? Where does the data come from? Where should the data go? Who should request the data? What are the business conditions? It now much sounds like you're using/choosing the wrong tools for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different libraries to convert from diferent java objects to JSON

For example the library json-simple http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

In the json-simple page you can see some examples of encoding,decoding, and JSP & AJAX with these library.

Answer (score 0):

Structure a Java object in a similar fashion and then use a serialization mechanism
such as json-simple or xstream with Json Driver

for instance
new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.toXML(object);

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Create JSONObject.
Create JSONArray.

Merge.

Thanks guy. Appreciate.