# How do I create a 3d JSON array?

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm wondering how I would create a simple JSON array in the following format:

```
["Question Category"
    ["Question text?"
         [A: "value", B: "value", C: "value", D: "value"]
    ]
]
```

I've never used JSON before, but I need for the data to be in JSON to implement it properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Create JSON Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455880/how-to-create-json-array)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this :

```
{
"Question category" : {
     "Question text?" : {
         "A":"value",
         "B": "value" ...
      }
   }
}
```

There are [a lot of examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098276/nested-json-objects-do-i-have-to-use-arrays-for-everything) on StackOverflow about nested JSON

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, you can use objects and arrays. What you might want is arrays of objects.

like so:

```
{
    "category1": [
        {
            "text": "Question text",
            "answers": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        },
        {
            "text": "Question text",
            "answers": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        },
        {
            "text": "Question text",
            "answers": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        }
    ], 
    "category2": [
        {
            "text": "Question text",
            "answers": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        },
        {
            "text": "Question text",
            "answers": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        },
        {
            "text": "Question text",
            "answers": ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
        }
    ]
}
```